# Why is there a difference between the candlestick data on coinigy versus the data that binance provides?

Tags: api

The candlestick data on coinigy.com does not match the binance official API. See the screenshot below:

[image]

Especially the open and close are very different, does anyone know why this is the case and if I can get the historic candlestick data from coinigy itself?

I think this is pretty weird because Coinigy is there for technical analysis and should be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Coinigy appears to use data from multiple exchanges, whereas Binance is just one exchange and their data is only for their exchange only.

Answer (score 1):

> why this is the case

Your chart is displaying UTC+1, the Binance data is UTC.

> can get the historic candlestick data from coinigy itself

Coinigy has an API https://www.coinigy.com/bitcoin-api/